# Use IN in any column in a Cassandra Table

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I want to be able to use `IN` in any column in any order in Cassandra

So I have the next table:

```
CREATE TABLE test (a TEXT, b TEXT, c TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (a, b, c));
```

and this data:

```
INSERT INTO test (a, b, c) VALUES ('a1', 'b1', 'c1');
INSERT INTO test (a, b, c) VALUES ('a2', 'b2', 'c2');
```

This query works:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE c IN ('c1', 'c2') AND b IN ('b1') ALLOW FILTERING;
```

But if you remove the `b IN` it gives this error:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE c IN ('c1', 'c2') ALLOW FILTERING;
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="IN 
restrictions are not supported on indexed columns"
```

Seems like if I want to use `IN` in a column I should have used `IN` in some previous columns?

Is there a way to avoid this?

Modifying the Schema is `valid` but I need to use Cassandra and allow filtering through any columns (if there's no need to filter thought a columns then there would be no `IN` clause for that column).

Thanks for reading.

P.S: I know you are not supposed to use `ALLOW FILTERING` please assume there's no other way.

Edit: Seems like they may have fixed this?: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14344

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of confusion cassandra's primary keys.
In order to respond to your question, i think you need to understand how cassandra primary keys are working internally.

When you are creating a Primary key with multiple fields like in your case:

```
CREATE TABLE test (a TEXT, b TEXT, c TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (a, b, c));
```

- "a" will be the ***partition key***, you can imagine it as a hash that will chose the partition on which data will be distributed.
- b and c will be the ***clustering keys***, these keys will be like a sorted list of your data and c will be nested in each b value, that means that you have to provide b in order to do constraints on c.

The cassandra documentation states that you can only use In clause on last column of the partition key and the last of the clustering key, but attention you'll have to provide all the other clustering keys.

So basically there is no way to do that in one table.

You should think of a tradeOff of your query flexibility vs data duplication.
One solution will be to denormalize your data in 2 tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test1 (a TEXT, b TEXT, c TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (a, b));
CREATE TABLE test2 (a TEXT, b TEXT, c TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (c, a, b));
```

By doing so, you will be able to query each table depending on your use case.
The following queries will work:

```
SELECT * FROM test2 WHERE c IN ('c1', 'c2');
SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE a IN ('a1', 'a2');
SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE b IN ('b1', 'b2') ALLOW FILTERING;
```

And so on, i think you got the point.
But really try to do the best tradeoff, in order to minimize the allow filtering usage. and remember that the queries on partition keys directly will be the fastest.

Comment: seems like they may have fixed this?:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14344

Comment: I see the issue is unresolved yet, but it's nice to know they will introduce this kind of behaviour.

Comment: Whenever you have to use "allow filtering", its a hint that you will run into trouble.